# How can I optimise this segment of code into a few lines? (Python 3.X)

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, optimization

I'm stuck with this giant segment of code, that has to be optimised. Thing is, I can't get it to work.

```
if condition1 == 0:
    A_value1 = (1/6)
    A_value2 = (1/8)
if condition1 == 1:
    A_value1 = (1/2)
    A_value2 = (1/8)
if condition1 == 2:
    A_value1 = (5/6)
    A_value2 = (1/8)
if condition1 == 3:
    A_value1 = (1/6)
    A_value2 = (3/8)
if condition1 == 4:
    A_value1 = (1/2)
    A_value2 = (3/8)
if condition1 == 5:
    A_value1 = (5/6)
    A_value2 = (3/8)
if condition1 == 6:
    A_value1 = (1/6)
    A_value2 = (5/8)
if condition1 == 7:
    A_value1 = (1/2)
    A_value2 = (5/8)
if condition1 == 8:
    A_value1 = (5/6)
    A_value2 = (5/8)

if condition2 == 0:
    B_value1 = (1/6)
    B_value2 = (1/8)
if condition2 == 1:
    B_value1 = (1/2)
    B_value2 = (1/8)
if condition2 == 2:
    B_value1 = (5/6)
    B_value2 = (1/8)
if condition2 == 3:
    B_value1 = (1/6)
    B_value2 = (3/8)
if condition2 == 4:
    B_value1 = (1/2)
    B_value2 = (3/8)
if condition2 == 5:
    B_value1 = (5/6)
    B_value2 = (3/8)
if condition2 == 6:
    B_value1 = (1/6)
    B_value2 = (5/8)
if condition2 == 7:
    B_value1 = (1/2)
    B_value2 = (5/8)
if condition2 == 8:
    B_value1 = (5/6)
    B_value2 = (5/8)

if condition3 == 0:
    C_value1 = (1/6)
    C_value2 = (1/8)
if condition3 == 1:
    C_value1 = (1/2)
    C_value2 = (1/8)
if condition3 == 2:
    C_value1 = (5/6)
    C_value2 = (1/8)
if condition3 == 3:
    C_value1 = (1/6)
    C_value2 = (3/8)
if condition3 == 4:
    C_value1 = (1/2)
    C_value2 = (3/8)
if condition3 == 5:
    C_value1 = (5/6)
    C_value2 = (3/8)
if condition3 == 6:
    C_value1 = (1/6)
    C_value2 = (5/8)
if condition3 == 7:
    C_value1 = (1/2)
    C_value2 = (5/8)
if condition3 == 8:
    C_value1 = (5/6)
    C_value2 = (5/8)
```

A_value1, B_value1 and C_value1 alternate between 1/6, 3/6 and 5/6.

A_value2, B_value2 and C_value2 alternate between 1/8, 3/8 and 5/8.

I've tried loops, ranges etc., but my efforts have been in vain. Can it be done in a single loop/range(?)-segment or must it be split into condition1, condition2 and condition3. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might be running into the X Y Problem. What is it you're trying to do?http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Those conditions look like arbitrary menu options, which are notoriously difficult to tidy up. However, there is a bit you can do. Since the values are uniform across conditions, you can store them in a dictionary and look them up as needed. Store the conditions in a `list` and then build up a `list` of values.

```
c = [condition1, condition2, condition3]
vals = []
lookup = {0:(1/6, 1/8), 1:(1/2, 1/8), 2:(5/6, 1/8), 3:(1/6, 3/8), 4:(1/2, 3/8),
          5:(5/6, 3/8), 6:(1/6, 5/8), 7:(1/2, 5/8), 8:(5/6, 5/8)

for i in range(3):
    vals.append(lookup[condition[i]])
```

You would then refer to `A_value1` as `vals[0][0]`, `C_value2` as `vals[2][1]`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce lists of possible values and get your `A_value1` etc from the list of values based on the remainder of division of the conditions by 3, and `A_value2` based on the result of integer division of the conditions by 3:

```
values1 = [1/6, 3/6, 5/6]
values2 = [1/8, 3/8, 5/8]
A_value1 = values1[condition1 % 3]
A_value2 = values2[condition1 // 3]
B_value1 = values1[condition2 % 3]
B_value2 = values2[condition2 // 3]
C_value1 = values1[condition3 % 3]
C_value2 = values2[condition3 // 3]
```

Comment: I think that might be a little *too* clever

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Yes that's horrible. For a simple solution, what about you create a hard-coded array with your assignments. They seem to be the same in each section.

```
values = [[(1/6), (1/8)], [(1/2), (1/8)], [(5/6), (5/8)] ....]
```

Then `c_value1` will be `values[condition3][0]`, `c_value2` will be `values[condition3][1]` etc.

You can attack the `array` with the `condition value`, as the `index`.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mathematical relationship here:

```
def f(condition):
    return ((condition % 3)*2 + 1)/6, ((condition // 3)*2 + 1)/8

A_value1, A_value2 = f(condition1)
B_value1, B_value2 = f(condition2)
C_value1, C_value2 = f(condition3)
```

I would also find a way not to have data in my variables (like `condition1`, `condition2` would probably be better as a single `conditions` list).

In code, this would allow us to do something like this:

```
# we wouldn't need this if we already avoided building condition1
conditions = [condition1, condition2, condition3]

A, B, C = [f(c) for c in conditions]

# now we can get back the values as A[0] and A[1] instead of A_value1 and A_value2:
A_value1, A_value2 = A
```

Notice that I suggest not ever building `condition1` in the first place. Having numbers in variable names is almost always better as an array with one name.